# How to make a layout like walkman in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am new with android layouts,I want to creat a layout like this image

[image]

as you know its sony walkman ui
I just want a background like it and some like those boxes..
this is my layout

```
enter code here<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Hafez" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/music_library_albums_header" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg_gradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_gradient" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tiles_bg"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:minHeight="10dp"
        android:minWidth="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Liberary"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:text="Chose what you want"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I really confused about make its background..As you see there is an image on top and its till midele of screen and after that we see a gradient in bottom of screen..But I cant set gradient to start after top image and continues till end of screen..
I want something like a screen with to part.Tob and bottom and in top I set image and in bottom a gradient and other boxes come in front of them..Is there any way to do this?
Thanks for your helps

Comment: image is not visible upload it to some site and link tat image

Comment: I tried to add image to my post but I didn't have enough reputation so I changed Image address to able to post here,Thanks for your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way is crate linear layout with back ground image.
above layout take one text view and grid view 3*3 row and columns.

implemented the gridview layout with image and text views